# String to complex number

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Consider the following list

```
MyList= {-0.0000396, -0.0000187167, "0.10259130990561813-0.0677132394802944i"}

Head /@ MyList (* -> {Real, Real, String} *)
```

In fact, the `String` is a complex number.

Is there an easy way of converting `MyList` to `MyNewList` such that

```
Head /@ MyNewList (* -> {Real, Real, Complex} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myList = {-0.0000396, -0.0000187167, "0.10259130990561813-0.0677132394802944i"} ;

myNewList = myList/.{x_, y_, z_} :> {x, y, ToExpression@StringReplace[z, "i" -> "I"]}
```

> {-0.0000396, -0.0000187167, 0.102591 - 0.0677132 I}

```
Head /@ myNewList
```

> {Real, Real, Complex}

Answer (score 2):

For a general case, in which the string may be in any position, also this is possible:

```
MyList /. s_String :> ToExpression[ToUpperCase[s]]
```

Care should be taken if the numbers come from another program using the common scientific notation, such as 1.0E+7. In this case, the following may help:

```
myList /. s_String :> ToExpression[StringReplace[ToUpperCase[s], "E" -> "*^"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {-0.0000396, -0.0000187167, "0.10259-0.06771i"};

list /. a_String :> Interpreter["ComplexNumber"] @ a
```

{-0.0000396, -0.0000187167, 0.10259 - 0.06771 I}

Listing of all interpreters:

[Setting up Input Interpreters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/InterpretingStrings.html)

Answer (score 1):

A little more general:

```
myList = {-0.0000396, -0.0000187167, "0.10259130990561813-0.0677132394802944i"}
(ToExpression /@ myList) /. i -> I
Head /@ %
```